# How TikZ uses $ for calculations of relative coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, catcodes

The following code `\node at ($(tag-node) + (2.5,0)$)` allows to place a node by calculating `$(tag-node) + (2.5,0)$`.

Does TikZ do that by changing the catcode of `$` ?

Comment: You can see https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools

Comment: The short answer is that TikZ uses its own parser.  Everything from `\path` to `;` basically ignores LaTeX protocols.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Ti*k*Z doesn't change the `\catcode` of `$`. Indeed, if you try to change yourself the `\catcode` of `$` TikZ will give an error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math
-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and migh
t cause unrecoverable errors.
```

TikZ assumes that `$` is a math-shift character and uses a parser to check for that. In `tikz.code.tex` there is this code:

```
\def\tikz@@@scan@@absolute#1({%
  \tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar{$}%$
  {\tikz@parse@calculator#1(}
  {\tikz@scan@no@calculator#1(}%
}%
```

The `\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode` is responsible for giving the error above in case `` \catcode`$ != 3 ``. Then `\pgfutil@ifnextchar{$}` checks if the character following the `(` is a `$`, and uses `\tikz@parse@calculator` in that case.

In `tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex` there is the definition of `\tikz@parse@calculator`:

```
\def\tikz@parse@calculator#1(${%$
  \def\tikz@cc@command{#1}%
  \begingroup%
    %
    % Parse main computation. It's a series of optional factors in front
    % of coordinates.
    %
    \pgf@xa=0pt% We accumulate the result in here.
    \pgf@ya=0pt%
    \tikz@cc@parse+%
}%

\def\tikz@cc@parse{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar${%$
    % Ok, we found the end...
    \tikz@cc@end%
  }
  {\pgfutil@ifnextchar+{%
      % Ok, we found a coordinate...
      \tikz@cc@add%
    }{%
      \pgfutil@ifnextchar-{%
        \tikz@cc@sub%
      }{%
        \tikzerror{+ or - expected}%
        \tikz@cc@end$%$
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
```

The macro `\tikz@parse@calculator` will use `\tikz@cc@parse` which will parse the expression and eventually check for the ending `$` and finish the calculation. All of that assuming `` \catcode`$=3 ``.

Comment: What an answer ! Thanks for all the details. :-)